# Do the solutions of parabolic PDE problems with different initial conditions converge to each other?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, cauchy-problem

Let's say we have a parabolic PDE system:

$$ 
(PDE) \hspace{0.5cm} u_t+f(u)_x=\mu \cdot u_{xx},
$$
where $x \in A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $t \in [0,T]$ and $u \in  \mathbb{R}^n, \: n\geq 2$. And let's consider the different initial conditions:

$$(IC1) \hspace{0.5cm}    
u(x,0)= \begin{cases}
u_l, x<0 \\[2ex]
u_r, x>0
\end{cases}
$$

$$(IC2) \hspace{0.5cm}    
u(x,0)= \begin{cases}
0, x<-a \\[2ex]
u_l, -a<x<0 \\[2ex]
u_r, 0<x<a\\[2ex]
0, x>a
\end{cases}
$$

$$(IC3) \hspace{0.5cm}    
u(x,0)= 
\begin{cases}
0, x<-a-\sigma\\[2ex]
smooth \: function_1, -a-\sigma<x<-a+\sigma \\[2ex]
u_l, -a+\sigma<x<-\sigma \\[2ex]
smooth \: function_2, -\sigma<x<\sigma \\[2ex]
u_r, \sigma<x<a-\sigma \\[2ex]
smooth \: function_3, a-\sigma<x<a+\sigma \\[2ex]
0, x>a+\sigma
\end{cases}
$$
where $u_l$ and $u_r$ are constants. Initial conditions $(IC1)$  are the usual Riemann conditions. Initial conditions $(IC2)$ are derived from $(IC1)$ by applying on it a cut off function that is equal to 1 on $[-a,a]$ and zero elsewhere. Conditions $(IC3)$ are derived from $(IC2)$ by using convolution with a moliffier $\varphi_{\sigma}$.

As far as I know solutions of the problems $(PDE)-(IC1)$, $(PDE)-(IC2)$, $(PDE)-(IC3)$ exist. And we see that when $\sigma \rightarrow 0$, $(IC3)$ converge to $(IC2)$, and when $a \rightarrow\infty$,  $(IC2)$ converge to $(IC1)$.

**I am interested if:**

1. solutions of $(PDE)-(IC3)$ converge to the solutions of $(PDE)-(IC2)$ when $\sigma \rightarrow 0$, and
2. solutions of $(PDE)-(IC2)$ converge to the solutions of $(PDE)-(IC1)$ when $a \rightarrow \infty$?

For the problem I am  currently working on it would be great if the answer to the question number 2. is yes. And if the answer to the question number 1. is yes I would use it in the future.

Some good reference in the literature would be very useful. And writing the answer would be great too. Thank you in advance.